# No Webpage was found for the address Azurewebsite

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core

I'm getting this
`No web page was found for the web address: https://limbu.azurewebsites.net/`
Everything worked fine in development but after publishing I get this error.
I can navigate to Views by typing in url but not the index page. I'm also not able to perform Register and login functions from controller in published website.
My Startup

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddRazorPages();
            if (Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") == "Production")
            {
                services.Configure<IServiceProvider>(options => {
                    options.GetService<AppDbContext>().Database.Migrate();
                }).AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options => {
                    options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("AzureSqlConnection"));
                    //options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging(true);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(_config.GetConnectionString("Connection")));
            }
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
            }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            services.AddTransient<IMailService, SendGridMailService>();
            services.AddHostedService<TimedHostedServices>();
            services.AddScoped<IGetGlobalCovidData, GetGlobalCovidData>();
            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            }).AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
            services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.HeaderName = "XSRF-TOKEN");
            //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += //This code is security risk as it validates all certificates
            //    (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>                 //Not to be used for production and used this instance as I trust the 
            //    {                                                       //The site I'm pulling data from
            //        return errors == SslPolicyErrors.None;
            //    };
            //services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder => {                                             //This code is security risk as it displays all sensitive data
            //    loggingBuilder.AddConsole()                                                     //Not recommended for production
            //        .AddFilter(DbLoggerCategory.Database.Command.Name, LogLevel.Information);
            //    loggingBuilder.AddDebug();
            //});
        }
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
            });
        }
```

Please advise me on what I should provide for debugging.
my `.cshtml` build action is -content and donotcopy
.cs build action is -c# compiler and donotcopy

Comment: can you check what is the error in kudu?

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan How do I do that? Is it the latest file ffrom crashdump?

Comment: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Diagnostic-Log-Stream

Comment: Hi, I'm looking at /api/logstream/kudu/trace in Kudu and it's taking forever. I'm i doing the right thing ?

Comment: Hi @Sajeetharan I tried this
C:\home>dotnet \home\site\wwwroot\TravelMate.dll
Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'LimbuwanAzureSQL'.
I don't know if this is what I'm supposed to do but that is not my user. Where is this user coming from ?

Comment: I solved this problem. Database for production was not updated to reflect Development.

Comment: Sorry just now i saw your responses! hope that kudu reference helped

Comment: Hi, @Sajeetharan. Yes, It helped me narrow down where to look. It's nice to learn new debugging tools. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the users who are getting the same issue, There could be different root causes for 404 error messages. Sub-status codes will help you understand the issue better.

You may check whether the site files are deployed correctly or not through [Kudu Console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Diagnostic-Log-Stream). Also, suggest you [Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs) for web apps in Azure App Service incase if you haven’t enabled earlier to check the complete error details and root cause.